# Long-polling Slowing Down Web App

Tags: javascript, jquery, long-polling

This is more of a concept question as I am trying to learn more about long-polling, in Javascript/jQuery specifically. I have a web app where I am long-polling (websockets are not an option right now) to a json file. I have run some tests and after leaving the app open for some time, it starts to slow down and later seems to start getting stuck. Using Chrome, I've checked the developer tools and the memory starts going through the roof, as with the listeners (>5000) around 1 1/2 hours of up time. I've searched and searched but can't find forums that pinpoint this problem and solution. In my code, I am using setInterval every 30 seconds. What do I need to do in order to keep the memory and listeners count low, and make sure the app does not overload and get slow? The function of the app requires it to stay up for long periods of time.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: does the function inside of the `setInterval` add any listeners with `.on()` or add any elements to the DOM?

Comment: Without seeing the code it's very hard to give advice. Only thing I have to say is re-use the same variables whenever possible. Another thing you might want to try is the doTimeout plugin for jQuery (http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/) which might help you keep your code clean and easy to read/manage.

Comment: "as with the listeners (>5000)" --- uhm, 5000 of what?

Comment: @A.O. Yes, I have 3 `.on()` listeners inside? That helps me understand a bit better. Is there a way to "clear" them without stopping the polling?

Comment: @zerkms over 5000 event listeners

Comment: @HamzaKubba I am now looking at the link you provided. It seem like it may help a bit. This showed up nowhere while Googling lol.

Comment: @Martavis P.: what kind of event listeners? Not sure I see how event listeners are relevant to long-polling question

Comment: @zerkms I have a few of them: mouse events, drag and drop, swipe, and long-click. Is that what you're asking about? The relevance come in through some insight I read stating that having the listeners' count go that high should not happen. Therefore, I'm trying to learn about it and felt it was worth mentioning just in case.

Comment: Yes, before you use `.on()` for any elements you should clear any event listeners tied to them already by using `.off()`, this should help keep the event listeners down, a bunch of extra loose hanging listeners can quickly slow down your js performance. Also if you are editing/adding any DOM elements, make sure to clear all references them so you dont build up a huge detached dom tree. Using `empty()` on any wrappers/containers can assist with that...

Comment: @Martavis P.: oh okay, I see now thanks

Comment: and having that many is not necessarily a problem in itself, but can become one quickly without managing them correctly

Comment: @A.O. that makes complete sense! I'm coming from C# and didn't have to worry much about this. Javascript is so much better to learn first lol. Thanks guys for helping and I would like to mark this as an answer if you don't mind pasting that below.

Comment: I am running tests using `.off()` and I already see a huge improvement! In 3 mins, the highest number of listeners is 30! For future people having the same issue with long-polling, make sure you remember to use that method to clean up as @A.O. stated above.